# Adding class active on one click only

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a class active, every time a click on a link but for now, it is only adding if I double click on it.

Here my HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Deposit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Credit</a></li>
</ul>
  <div class="box active" id="deposit">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="account">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="credit">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="random">
  <p>This is a random text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li{
  list-style:none;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover{
      color: blue;
    }  
  }

}
ul{
  background: black;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box{
  height: 200px;
}
#deposit{
  background: green;
}
#account{
  background: pink;
}
#credit{
  background: blue;
}
li a.active{
  color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.box').hide();
  $('li a').on("click", function(){

    if(!$('li a').hasClass('active')){   
      $(this).addClass('active');   
    }
    else{
      $('li a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });  
});
```

Here my pen: http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/MbyXvP

How can I add the class active to the link when I click on it and remove that same class from any other link if it exists?
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `active` class from all `a` and then add `active` class to clicked `a` like following.

```
$('div.box').hide();
$('li a').on("click", function() {
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('div.box').hide();
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $('div.box').eq(index).show();
});
```

[**UPDATED CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbrpBN)

Comment: Hope you dont mind checking my updated snippet. Wanna be able to show the content of a specific box when I click on each link but it does not work.
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/MbyXvP

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('div.box').hide();
  $('li a').on("click", function(){
      $('li a').not($(this)).removeClass('active');

      $(this).toggleClass('active');   
  });  
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style:none;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover{
      color: blue;
    }  
  }
  
}
ul{
  background: black;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box{
  height: 200px;
}
#deposit{
  background: green;
}
#account{
  background: pink;
}
#credit{
  background: blue;
}
li a.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Deposit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Credit</a></li>
</ul>
  <div class="box active" id="deposit">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="account">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="credit">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div id="random">
  <p>This is a random text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only modify the elements on which click happened. You could do something like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div.box').hide();
  $('li a').on("click", function(event) {
    let $ele = $(event.target);
    $('li a').not($ele).removeClass('active');
    $ele.toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    &: hover {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
ul {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
}
#deposit {
  background: green;
}
#account {
  background: pink;
}
#credit {
  background: blue;
}
li a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Deposit</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Credit</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="box active" id="deposit">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="account">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="credit">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sunt voluptates reprehenderit similique nostrum eius repudiandae odio eos obcaecati doloremque quam quos, officiis veritatis blanditiis soluta molestiae iusto illo corrupti.</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="random">
  <p>This is a random text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the existing active class first then add the same class on click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.box').hide();
   $('li a').on("click", function(){
      $('li a').removeClass('active'); 
      $(this).addClass('active');     
   }); 
});
```